# Restrict server login via LDAP hostObject objectClass and host Attribute

Tags: ldap

How do I configure my LDAP server to allow all hosts except one? All users by default have the `host: *` attribute, which allows any user to login to any server. I've tried the following regex, but it seems regular expressions are not supported here :

```
host: !(*test.example.com*)
```

I've refered to [this page](http://thornelabs.net/documentation/2013/02/01/linux-restrict-server-login-via-ldap-hostobject-objectclass-and-host-attribute.html) to set the `host` attribute.

LDAP Version : 2.3.43-12

Answer (score 0):

To restrict user login to unix accounts on a host basis, please see the LDAP documentation at

```
         https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM
```

under the section

```
         "Allowing logins on a per-host basis"
```

First of all you have to add the ldapns schema, uually supplied in the libpam-ldap package and then add the specific restrictions for each user.

Note that references to editing the configuration file are for the old way that LDAP was configured and now you have to change the configuration by creating an LDIF file with the specifications required and then apply them using the ldapadd (new entry) or ldapmodify (change existing entry) command with -f path_to_the_ldif oarameter.

If you look at the bottom of the Debian/Wiki section it gives a suggestion as to how to accomplish an all hosts except X expression.

```
        negation (!host) capability. E.g.:

 (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=$username)  (|(host=$hostname)(host=$fqdn)(&(host=\\*)(!(|(host=!$hostname)(host=!$fqdn))))))
```